# Finding which pthreads are available when implementing a thread pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, pthreads, threadpool

I'm trying to implement a basic thread pool class using pthreads in C++. What is a simple way to know if an incoming task can be assigned to a given thread in the pool? I.e, how can I check which threads are not running anymore?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you currently keep information about the threads in the pool? Do you have a vector or array? Can you make it into vector of structures to keep a "busy" flag in it? Or add a second vector with the status?

Comment: If `pthreads` support atomic operations a simple solution can be anytime a thread picks a task, decrements a counter and whenever the thread has done it's job increment the counter. the value of counter show available thread count.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I keep a vector of pthreads. Let's say I create a vector of Boolean flags indicating if a pthread is busy. How do I update this vector of booleans? Even if I update it in the last line in the function the pthread runs, still there's a possibility the function didn't entirely finish and the flag was already updated. The same problem can arise when using a counter.

Comment: A thread pool typically have a set of existing but idle threads (waiting on a condition variable or similar). When the thread is supposed to do something it calls a "work" function, and when that function returns it goes back to being idle. Instead of going directly back to being idle when the "work" function returns, it sets or clears the flag. And before calling the "work" function it does the opposite with the flag. The "work" function itself don't have to care about it.